# What's the purpose of using MLM when pretraining?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, nlp, transformer

If BERT is a stack of transformer encoders, and the encoder already operates bidirectionally, understanding both left and right contexts and generating contextual embeddings, what is the purpose of pretraining BERT using MLM ? Does it aim to improve the contextual embeddings even better ? Could someone please provide an explanation on this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you train any model, you need to train it on a specific task and its associated loss function. Masked-language modelling is the token-level task used for training transformer encoders like BERT and RoBERTa on unlabeled text. While the transformer encoder architecture enables it to "operate bidirectionally", you still need a loss that exercises such bidirectionality so that the model is actually trained.

Therefore, you can't have a BERT model (nor BERT contextual embeddings) unless you train it in some task like masked language modelling.

Comment: Why didn't they just use transformer encoder right away, since it's already work bidirectionally, I mean why did they have to train ?

Comment: And about MLM, I read somewhere saying MLM is for producing contextual embeddings because the model process left and right context of the mask, so BERT contextual embedding is better than vanila transformer encoder's contextual embedding ?

Comment: You need to train the model using a loss, and only then can you extract embeddings from the trained model. When you say  "Vanilla transformer encoder's contextual embeddings", you are not specifying a loss, so it does not make sense to say so.

Comment: Are you saying that if I only use the vanilla transformer's encoder, I can't extract the contextual embedding ?

Comment: No. I am saying that BERT is a vanilla transformer encoder trained on a MLM task and a NSP task, and RoBERTa is a vanilla transformer encoder trained on a MLM task, and that just saying "vanilla transformer encoder" says nothing about the model and it can refer to any transformer encoder.

Comment: Anyway let me understand this, so you have to train BERT and Roberta on a specific tasks, so that you can able to extract the embeddings right ? I'm actually want to know can the vanila the transformer encoder also output the embedding too, without pre-training like BERT or Roberta ? By vanilla transformer encoder I mean just the encoder part of the original architecture in the "Attention is all you need" paper

Comment: The "Attention is all you need" paper is just the description of the Transformer architecture. It does not have a pre-trained model that can be reused. This way, it does not make sense to "extract embeddings from it" because there is not "it".

Comment: Original Transformer doesn't have a pre-trained model that can be reused ?? So if I want to use I have to train the architecture again ?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: The pre-trained model trend started in NLP with [ULMfit](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.06146), [ELMo](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.05365) and [BERT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805) in 2018. The [original transformer article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) is from 2017.